# Java String replace with Regular expression with new pattern in Array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, replace

I got an issue that I'm not able to solve

I have a paragraph that contains some keywords need to be replaced with new values which are stored in an array

**Example:**

> **Paragraph:** "My most favorite fruit is [0], but I also like [1] and [3]"
>
> **Array:** fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape"]

My expectation is: `My most favorite fruit is Banana, but I also like Orange and Grape`

Could you help me to find a solution for this?

I have tried to convert my sentence into Array of String like this:

`["My most favorite fruit is ","[0]",", but I also like ","[1]"," and ","[3]"]`

After that, I replace `[0]` to `0`, I got this:

`["My most favorite fruit is ","0",", but I also like ","1"," and ","3"]`

I tend to replace `0`, `1`, and `3` in above array into value of `fruits[0]`, `fruits[1]`, `fruits[3]` then convert that array into a completed string

But I think it's not the best solution, because if I got an input sentence like this: `"2[2]"` then I will receive the output is **AppleApple**, whereas the Expectation is **2Apple**

Comment: If your issue "cannot be solved" why are you posting it?

Answer (score 4):

Java's [string formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) has a built-in syntax for this. The general format is:

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

so you can use e.g. `%1$s` to mean the first format parameter, `%2s` the second etc. Note that the indexes are one-based, not zero-based.

e.g.

```
String[] fruits = {"Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape"};
System.out.format(
    "My most favorite fruit is %1$s, but I also like %2$s and %4$s",
    fruits);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use String.replace

```
String sentence = "My most favorite fruit is [0], but I also like [1] and [3]";
String[] replacements = {"Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape"};
for(int i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++)
    sentence = sentence.replace("[" + i + "]", replacements[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change the format of `paragraph` then you might start from this snippet.

```
String paragraph = "My most favorite fruit is %s, but I also like %s and %s";
String[] fruits = {"Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape"};
System.out.printf(paragraph, fruits[0], fruits[1], fruits[2]);
```

output

```
My most favorite fruit is Banana, but I also like Orange and Apple
```

**edit** Another solution where don't have to maintain the positional parameters of the fruits could be.

```
String paragraph = "My most favorite fruit is {0}, but I also like {1} and {3}";
Object[] fruits = {"Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape"};
MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(paragraph);
System.out.println(mf.format(fruits));
```

output

```
My most favorite fruit is Banana, but I also like Orange and Grape
```

Comment: I want to replace with exact index in source Paragraph, just like [0] should be replaced with fruits[0], and so on ...

Comment: @mrzenky Does it mean the placeholders can be in a random order. E.g. `John Doe likes [2] and [1], but don't like [3]` should result as `John Doe likes Apple and Orange, but don't like Grape`?

Comment: @mrzenky you can use `%1$s` for that. See [Formatter's syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code (see [demo](http://ideone.com/LAaDoB)):

```
ArrayList<String> fruits_arr = new ArrayList<String>(); // Just initializing the array
        fruits_arr.add("Banana");        
        fruits_arr.add("Orange");
        fruits_arr.add("Apple");
        fruits_arr.add("Grape");
    String[] fruits = fruits_arr.toArray(new String[0]);  
    String s = "My most favorite fruit is [0], but I also like [1] and [3]";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)\\]").matcher(s); // Initializing Matcher
    while (m.find()) {                          // Iterate over matches
        int num = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)); // If there is a match, Group 1 has digits
        String replacement = "";
        if (num < fruits.length) {          // If the number is lower than fruit element count
               replacement =fruits[num];   // Get the array element
        } else {
            replacement = m.group();        // Else, use the whole match (e.g. [9])
        }
        m.appendReplacement(result, replacement); // Append this replacement
    }
    m.appendTail(result);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

With `\[(\d+)]` you match any substring with `[`+`digits`+`]`, and capture the digit sequence into Group 1.

Comment: like you're using PHP for this ? could I use for java ?

Comment: I have re-written the code into Java. Yes, it is something similar to PHP, JS, and other languages where we perform string manipulations inside a callback function in a Replace function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
String str = "My most favorite fruit is [0], but I also like [1] and [3]";
String[] fruits = { "Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Grape" };

for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++)
{
    str = str.replaceAll("\\[" + i + "\\]", fruits[i]);
}
```